# Method to find where site definitions were used

Tags: 2007, site-definition

Is there a way to find out what site definitions were used to create sites? We are trying to remove some site definitions from our code base, but we want to make sure no sites are using them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have the required values in respective SPWeb objects *WebTemplate* and *Configuration* properties.

Some example of a console application [here](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=115).